# ITunes gift card

Tags: itunes

Good morning. Is it possible to change currency from dollar to rand,but I have to buy iTunes gift card and send to a friend for her to transfer into my bank account? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you're contacted and requested to buy gift cards to transfer to a third party that will reimburse you in cash or bank transfers, that is a warning sign for fraud, money laundering, etc.

I would stay away from such arrangements entirely.